# I want autopostback on dropdownlist on Razor page not MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I want autopostback on dropdownlist on Razor page not MVC
I have this code but it not working, the intention is to call what has been select immediately for another process.

```
<select id="ddlDList" class="form-control" name="PredefineID" asp-items="@Model.ListModes" new { onchange = "DoPostBack();" }">

<option value="0">Please select</option>
 </select>
```

.......

```
public string DoPostBack()
    {
      …..  

        return listdefine;
    }
```

Comment: Is there a property called AutoPostBack or similar sort to call the function? I am not sure about the syntax though that you are using...

Comment: What i have there is not calling "public string DoPostBack()" event, I just need a proper way of write that in Razor Pages

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use ajax to get data from razor page handler:

html:

```
<select id="ddlDList" class="form-control" name="PredefineID" asp-items="@Model.ListModes" onchange=DoPostBack()>

<option value="0">Please select</option>
 </select>
```

js:

```
<script>
function DoPostBack() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "?handler=DoPostBack&&PredefineID=" + $("#ddlDList").val(),
            success: function (listdefine) {
                //get listdefine here
            }
        });
</script>
```

handler in cshtml.cs file:

```
public JsonResult OnGetDoPostBack(int PredefineID) {
            ...
            return new JsonResult(listdefine);
        }
```